# Placing layer name beside their symbols in legend using representations of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, legend, feature-class, representation

I want to place the layer name of my feature class (styled with a representation) beside (right hand side) its symbol in the legend of my map in ArcMap 10.1.

I know that the format can be changed via: legend > properties > theme > choose my layer and click "style" and then changing the legend elements' style from the list. However, if I use feature classes styled with representations I do not know how to do this. Using shapes it's no problem because I can adjust the description of the layer in the table of contents. However, this is not possible (or I don't know how to) when using representations.

These pictures visualize my question:

Standard legend style for Representations:
[image: Standard legend style for Representations]

Possible by changing the legend's style:

[image: Possible by changing the legend's style]

What I want to achieve:

[image: What I want]

Any hints or suggestions on how to solve my problem? Maybe there is a way of creating customized styles?

Answer (score 1):

To get a more custom legend, you may want to try these steps once you initially create the legend:

1. right click and select “properties”
2. Go to the “items” tab
3. click on the “style” button at the bottom of the window.  This provides a bunch of different legend options.  However, if you don’t see the style that you are looking for you can press “properties” to get even more options
4. If you still do not see the style you are looking for you can click on “more styles” and that will provide additional style choices

Answer (score 1):

First away is, create a definition query to display just "Rule_1", than create symbology by "Single Symbol", arcmap automatically with show just layer name.

Second away, if you have to use Categories for symbology.

1- Add new field to feature dataset

2- calculate the field with layer name (for feature that you wanna include your case "Rule_1")

3- Create symbology with this field

4- Remove other categories

5- Create Legend (Legend will be with your layer name)